RuntimeError ThePoetry configuration is invalid: - Additional properties are not allowed('group' was unexpected)
I was carrying out 'video captioning' by referring to GitHub 'https: //github.com/ yukw777/ VideoBLIP'.
This is setup stage
I tried 'poetry install' But, I got an error
This is my error
I think the part where the group is written like [tool.poetry.group.dev] in the pyproject.toml file is related to this error.
pyproject.toml
But, I don't know how to solve it
My Python3 version -> 3.10.12
My poetry version -> 1.1.12
It seemed to be a poetry version issue, so I changed the poetry version to 1.2.
But, I got an new error.
new error
So I set it back to version 1.1.12.
